# Getting the url of a Blob just uploaded to Azure storage via PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have no problem uploading a blob to Azure via PHP like this:

```
 $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("saskcontainer", $blob_name, $content);
```

but I cannot get the URL of the newly created blob. The api is pretty straight forwad for getting the url

```
 echo $blob->getUrl()
```

When I list the contents of a container it can get the url of each file no problem like this:

```
$blob_list = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs("saskcontainer");
$blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

foreach($blobs as $blob)
{
    echo $blob->getUrl()."<br />";
}
```

Great, but I just want one url (of the one uploaded), but the code below doesn't work:

```
$blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob("saskcontainer", $blob_name);
echo $blob->getUrl();
```

I get the error: Call to undefined method WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\GetBlobResult::getUrl()

I tried this as well :

```
$blob = $blobRestProxy->getUrl("saskcontainer", $blob_name);
echo $blob;
```

error: Call to undefined method WindowsAzure\Blob\BlobRestProxy::getUrl() 
libraries:

```
 require_once 'WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.php';
 use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
 use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: where is the library you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL for a blob follows the following pattern:

```
[http|https]://[account-name].[endpoint-suffix(usually blob.core.windows.net]/[container-name]/[blob-name]
```

Using this pattern you can construct the URL of the blob without getting it programmatically.

I looked up Azure SDK for PHP and I could not find a simple way to programmatically fetch the blob URL (but then I may be wrong). A convoluted way to fetch the URL programmatically would be to call `listBlobs` method and pass the blob name as `prefix` in `options` parameter for this operation. You will get just one blob in the result and then you can do the following to get the blob URL:

```
    $listBlobsOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
    $listBlobsOptions->setPrefix($blobName);
    $blob_list = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs($containerName, $listBlobsOptions);
    $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

    foreach($blobs as $blob)
    {
      echo $blob->getUrl()."<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Did this to get it programmatically: `foreach($blobs as $blob)
    {
        if($blob->getName() === $blob_name) {
          $returnUrl = $blob->getUrl();
        }
    }` it works, but then realized the pattern is always the same, so I just hard coded is with the file name as a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getBlobUrl($accountName, $container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $start, $expiry, $_signature) {
    /* Create the signed query part */
    $_parts = array();
    $_parts[] = 'sv=2015-04-05';
    $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
    $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
    $_parts[] = (!empty($start)) ? 'st=' . urlencode($start) : '';
    $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry)) ? 'se=' . urlencode($expiry) : '';
    $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions)) ? 'sp=' . $permissions : '';

    /* Create the signed blob URL */

    if ($accountName == 'devstoreaccount1') {
        $_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/'
                . $accountName . '/'
                . $container . '/'
                . $blob . '?'
                . implode('&', $_parts);
    } else {
        $_url = 'https://'
                . $accountName . '.blob.core.windows.net/'
                . $container . '/'
                . $blob . '?'
                . implode('&', $_parts);
    }

    return $_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question but there is more up to date solution.

You can use your Storage class to retrieve a url like you do with AWS.

```
$link = Storage::disk('azure')->url('your_filepath');
```

This will generate the same link as the above pattern.